# Controller Parameter giving a strange error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a wrote a project using spring boot my controller were just working fine until I have added
'params' to getmapping annotation

my PlaneTypeVersionedApi Interface down below;

```
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/version")
public interface PlaneTypeVersionedApi {

    @GetMapping(value = "/plane", params = "v1")
    ResponseEntity<String> getOnePlaneByProduce1(@RequestParam("plane-type")String planeType);
}
```

my PlaneTypeVersionedApiImpl Class down below;

```
@RestController
public class PlaneTypeVersionedApiImpl implements PlaneTypeVersionedApi {

    private final PlaneCallerService planeCallerService;

    public PlaneTypeVersionedApiImpl (PlaneCallerService planeCallerService) {
        this.planeCallerService = planeCallerService;
    }



@Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> getOnePlaneByProduce1(String planeType) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(planeCallerService.getPlaneType(planeType));
    }

}
```

when I try on Postman for my controller;

localhost:9080/version/plane?plane-type=light-weight?v1

I have 400 bad request and saying
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "v1" not met for actual request parameters: plane-type={light-weight?v1}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the query parameters on the url is not valid.

Here is the correct syntax : **localhost:9080/version/plane?plane-type=light-weight&v1**.

https://launchschool.com/books/http/read/what_is_a_url#querystringsparameters

Comment: thank you so much for your answer this is exactly what ı needed it

Answer (score 0):

your url is bad not sure what your intent use of **params**

example 1 valid url = **localhost:9080/version/plane?plane-type=light-weight&v1=**

using **@RequestParam("plane-type") String plane-type
@RequestParam("v1") String v1** is enough to get the value no need use of attribute **params**

example 2 if you want to use **params**

**@GetMapping(value = "/plane", params = {"v1"})** this mean you want **v1** value

```
ResponseEntity<String> getOnePlaneByProduce1(@RequestParam("v1")String v1);
```

example 3 you want both

**@GetMapping(value = "/plane", params = {"v1","plane-type"})** this mean you want **v1** value and **plane-type**

```
ResponseEntity<String> getOnePlaneByProduce1(@RequestParam("v1")String v1, @RequestParam("plane-type") String plane-type);
```

**params** option just mean that endpoint require to have those params if one you specific is not there it gonna complain